# Using Byte Buddy to expand Spring Boot's classpath

Tags: instrumentation, byte-buddy, aws-java-sdk, javaagents

The AWS SDK can locate API call interceptors via classpath scanning (looking for `software/amazon/awssdk/global/handlers/execution.interceptors` and instantiating classes specified there).

I'm writing a Java Agent with the intention of causing my interceptors to be locatable by the AWS SDK.

- My interceptor is bundled with the Java Agent.
- My interceptor implements AWS's `ExecutionInterceptor`.
- The AWS SDK is **not** bundled with my agent, because I'd like the end-user to provide their own AWS SDK version.

For regular standalone applications, this is a no-brainer, as the Java Agent is automatically added to the runtime classpath of the application. The AWS SDK finds my interceptors with no problem.

However, this approach completely breaks with Spring Boot applications where the AWS SDK is bundled as a dependency under `BOOT-INF/lib`. The reason boils down to Spring Boot's classloading hierarchy. My interceptor class can be found, but its loading fails due to inability to find AWS's `ExecutionInterceptor`, as it is loaded in a "lower" classloader in the hierarchy.

So I figured that my approach should be to somehow modify Spring Boot's classloader search. However, I'm facing these issues:

- At the time of the agent being called, Spring Boot's "lower" classloader isn't created yet.
- I am not entirely sure what it is that I need to instrument.

I've read of Byte Buddy being able to help in such "interesting" circumstances but haven't found a way to make this work yet. Any ideas?

(**EDIT**: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require code/packaging changes, hence the Java Agent approach)

(**EDIT**: Things I've tried)

Following Rafael's answer: The method in the SDK that resolves all interceptors is in the class `SdkDefaultClientBuilder`, and is called `resolveExecutionInterceptors`.

The following, then, works for standalone JARs which are not SpringBoot applications:

```java
    public static void installAgent(Instrumentation inst) {
        new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .with(RedefinitionStrategy.DISABLED)
            .type(ElementMatchers.nameEndsWith("SdkDefaultClientBuilder"))
            .transform(
                    new Transformer() {
                @Override
                public Builder<?> transform(Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription,
                        ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule module) {
                    return builder.visit(Advice.to(MyAdvice.class).on(ElementMatchers.named("resolveExecutionInterceptors")));
                }
            }
                    ).installOn(inst);
    }
```

For SpringBoot applications, however, it looks like the advice isn't applied at all. I am guessing that this is because the `SdkDefaultClientBuilder` type isn't even available at the time when the agent starts. It is available during SpringBoot's runtime, in a different classloader.

Comment: you can create a jar with the "normal" structure instead of the "BOOT-INF/lib to be used by whatever needs to be.  You can check the spring boot maven plugin https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-build.html#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar

Comment: Right. I should have added (and will edit the question soon) — I need a solution that doesn't require code changes or repackaging of the existing app

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your agent uses classes that are loaded with a different classloader?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn yes

Comment: Well, then the easiest way would be to use reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Byte Buddy allows you to inject code in any method of any class, so the first and only major thing you would need to find out would be where your interceptor is instantiated. This can typically be done by setting a breakpoint in the constructor of the interceptor in the working scenario and investigating the methods in the stack. Find out where the classes are discovered, for example the method where *software/amazon/awssdk/global/handlers/execution.interceptors* is read.

Once you have identified this method, you would need to find a way to manually extract the interceptors defined by your agent and to manually add them. For example, if the file-extracted interceptors are added to an argument of type `List<Interceptor>`, you could use Byte Buddy to modify this method to also add those of your agent.

Normally, you use Byte Buddy's `AgentBuilder` in conjunction with `Advice` to do so. Advice let's you inline code into another method as for example, assuming you find a method with an argument of type `List<Interceptor>`:

```
class MyAdvice {
  @Advice.OnMethodEnter
  static void enter(@Advice.Argument(0) List<Interceptor> interceptors) {
    interceptors.addAll(MyAgent.loadMyInterceptors());
  }
}
```

You can now inline this code into the method in question by:

```
class MyAgent {
  public static void premain(String arg, Instrumentation inst) {
    new AgentBuilder.Default().type(...).transform((builder, ...) -> builder
      .visit(Advice.to(MyAdvice.class).on(...))).install(inst);
  }
}
```

You might need to use `AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice` if the classes in question are not available on the agent's class loader where Byte Buddy resolves the advice using both the target and the agent class loader.

Comment: I have already tried this approach (see my recent edit). Thank you. That, however, works for standalone JAR's which are not SpringBoot applications. For SpringBoot, the injection isn't happening, and I'm guessing this is due to SpringBoot's classloader topology. At the time when the agent is run, none of the AWS SDK classes are even known.